# How do you follow an HTTP Redirect in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, http-redirect

I want to open a page up in node and process the contents in my application. Something like this seems to work well:

```
var opts = {host: host, path:pathname, port: 80};
http.get(opts, function(res) {
  var page = '';
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    page += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
     // process page
  });
```

This doesn't work, however, if the page returns an 301/302 redirect. How would I do that in a reusable way in case there are multiple redirects? Is there a wrapper module on top of the http to more easily handle processing http responses from a node application?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Is there a wrapper module on top of the http to more easily handle processing http responses from a node application?

[`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

[Redirection logic in request](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/86b99b671a3c86f4f963a6c67047343fd8edae8f/request.js#L762)

Comment: Why the living b'jesus isn't this part of the built-in http module?!

Comment: It is. It's called `http.request` the API is pretty simple.

Comment: Is it possible to have a callback for each redirect somehow? I'd like to store every single URL the request goes through. Couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: @Raynos, the request() method of the built-in `http` module does not follow redirects, therefore this is not part of the built-in `http` module.

Comment: This should be the top answer since it works as drop-in replacement to the built-in node client: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390241/589493

Comment: `request` is a pretty [bloated](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=request) module by today's standards. Folks prefer [cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch), which uses the native [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) implementation if run in a browser context, and brings the same API to Node.

Comment: `request` has been deprecated.

Comment: deprecated [indeed](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)

Answer (score 150):

If all you want to do is follow redirects but still want to use the built-in HTTP and HTTPS modules, I suggest you use https://github.com/follow-redirects/follow-redirects.

```
yarn add follow-redirects
npm install follow-redirects
```

All you need to do is replace:

```
var http = require('http');
```

with

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
```

... and all your requests will automatically follow redirects.

With TypeScript you can also install the types

```
npm install @types/follow-redirects
```

and then use

```
import { http, https } from 'follow-redirects';
```

Comment: This is now here: https://github.com/request/request/blob/d18cb487cf4e02740778d4bb464b5a1c7441d800/lib/redirect.js#L46

Comment: This is way better than the accepted answer featuring `request` which would add 20+ new dependencies to your module for such a simple task. Thank you for keeping npm modules lightweight, Oliver! :)

Comment: Doesn't work when I use it with audio hosted securely on s3.

Comment: Using TypeScript add this to your npm install:

    npm install @types/follow-redirects 

so you can use

    import {https} from 'follow-redirects';

This is a fantastic, simple, oh so efficient module. Merci Olivier !

Comment: I wasn't able to use things like [cacheable-lookup](https://github.com/szmarczak/cacheable-lookup) to work with this, unfortunately

Answer (score 31):

Make another request based on `response.headers.location`:

```
      const request = function(url) {
        lib.get(url, (response) => {
          var body = [];
          if (response.statusCode == 302) {
            body = [];
            request(response.headers.location);
          } else {
            response.on("data", /*...*/);
            response.on("end", /*...*/);
          };
        } ).on("error", /*...*/);
      };
      request(url);
```

Comment: This is the answer if you want to use built in http lib, follow `response.headers.location`

Answer (score 26):

**Update:**

Now you can follow all redirects with `var request = require('request');` using the `followAllRedirects` param.

```
request({
  followAllRedirects: true,
  url: url
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: is this complete code? your var is `http` but then you use a function called `request`

Comment: you cannot simply require('request'), this is an external module and needs to be downloaded & installed first -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
(npm install request)

Comment: `request` has been deprecated

Answer (score 22):

Here is my (recursive) approach to download JSON with plain node, no packages required.

```
import https from "https";

function get(url, resolve, reject) {
  https.get(url, (res) => {
    // if any other status codes are returned, those needed to be added here
    if(res.statusCode === 301 || res.statusCode === 302) {
      return get(res.headers.location, resolve, reject)
    }

    let body = [];

    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
      try {
        // remove JSON.parse(...) for plain data
        resolve(JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString()));
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
}

async function getData(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => get(url, resolve, reject));
}

// call
getData("some-url-with-redirect").then((r) => console.log(r));
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is function I use to fetch the url that have redirect:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

function get({path, host}, callback) {
    http.get({
        path,
        host
    }, function(response) {
        if (response.headers.location) {    
            var loc = response.headers.location;
            if (loc.match(/^http/)) {
                loc = new Url(loc);
                host = loc.host;
                path = loc.path;
            } else {
                path = loc;
            }
            get({host, path}, callback);
        } else {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```

it work the same as http.get but follow redirect.

Answer (score 3):

In case of PUT or POST Request. if you receive statusCode 405 or method not allowed. Try this implementation with "**request**" library, and add mentioned properties. 
      **followAllRedirects: true,

      followOriginalHttpMethod: true**

```
       const options = {
           headers: {
               Authorization: TOKEN,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json'
           },
           url: `https://${url}`,
           json: true,
           body: payload,
           followAllRedirects: true,
           followOriginalHttpMethod: true
       }

       console.log('DEBUG: API call', JSON.stringify(options));
       request(options, function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error) {
        console.log(response);
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have `https` server, change your url to use `https://` protocol.

I got into similar issue with this one. My url has `http://` protocol and I want to make a `POST` request, but the server wants to redirect it to `https`. What happen is that, turns out to be node http behavior sends the redirect request (next) in `GET` method which is not the case.

What I did is to change my url to `https://` protocol and it works.

Comment: This is one very particular example of redirect, and won't do anything for, say, tinyurls or bit.ly links.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a little bit of a necromancing post here, but...

here's a function that follows up to 10 redirects, and detects infinite redirect loops. also parses result into JSON

**Note - uses a callback helper (shown at the end of this post)**

( TLDR; full working demo in context [here](https://glitch.com/~node-tlds-json) or [remixed-version here](https://node-tlds-json-remix.glitch.me/))

```
function getJSON(url,cb){

    var callback=errBack(cb);
    //var callback=errBack(cb,undefined,false);//replace previous line with this to turn off logging

    if (typeof url!=='string') {
        return callback.error("getJSON:expecting url as string");
    }

    if (typeof cb!=='function') {
        return callback.error("getJSON:expecting cb as function");
    }

    var redirs = [url],
    fetch = function(u){
        callback.info("hitting:"+u);
        https.get(u, function(res){
            var body = [];
            callback.info({statusCode:res.statusCode});
            if ([301,302].indexOf(res.statusCode)>=0) {
                if (redirs.length>10) {
                    return callback.error("excessive 301/302 redirects detected");
                } else {
                    if (redirs.indexOf(res.headers.location)<0) {
                        redirs.push(res.headers.location);
                        return fetch(res.headers.location);
                    } else {
                        return callback.error("301/302 redirect loop detected");
                    }
                }
            } else {
              res.on('data', function(chunk){
                  body.push(chunk);
                  callback.info({onData:{chunkSize:chunk.length,chunks:body.length}});
              });
              res.on('end', function(){
                  try {
                      // convert to a single buffer
                      var json = Buffer.concat(body);
                      console.info({onEnd:{chunks:body.length,bodyLength:body.length}});

                      // parse the buffer as json
                      return callback.result(JSON.parse(json),json);
                  } catch (err) {

                      console.error("exception in getJSON.fetch:",err.message||err);

                      if (json.length>32) {
                        console.error("json==>|"+json.toString('utf-8').substr(0,32)+"|<=== ... (+"+(json.length-32)+" more bytes of json)");
                      } else {
                          console.error("json==>|"+json.toString('utf-8')+"|<=== json");
                      }

                      return callback.error(err,undefined,json);
                  }
              });
            }
        });
    };
    fetch(url);   
}
```

**Note - uses a callback helper (shown below)**

you can paste this into the node console and it should run as is.

( or for full working demo in context [see here](https://glitch.com/~node-tlds-json) )

```
var 

fs      = require('fs'),
https   = require('https');

function errBack (cb,THIS,logger) {

   var 
   self,
   EB=function(fn,r,e){
       if (logger===false) {
           fn.log=fn.info=fn.warn=fn.errlog=function(){};       
       } else {
           fn.log        = logger?logger.log   : console.log.bind(console);
           fn.info       = logger?logger.info  : console.info.bind(console);
           fn.warn       = logger?logger.warn  : console.warn.bind(console);
           fn.errlog     = logger?logger.error : console.error.bind(console);
       }
       fn.result=r;
       fn.error=e;
       return (self=fn);
   };


   if (typeof cb==='function') {
       return EB(

            logger===false // optimization when not logging - don't log errors
            ?   function(err){
                   if (err) {
                      cb (err);
                     return true;
                   }
                   return false;
               }

            :  function(err){
                   if (err) {
                      self.errlog(err);
                      cb (err);
                     return true;
                   }
                   return false;
               },

           function () {
               return cb.apply (THIS,Array.prototype.concat.apply([undefined],arguments));
           },
           function (err) {
               return cb.apply (THIS,Array.prototype.concat.apply([typeof err==='string'?new Error(err):err],arguments));
           }
       );
   } else {

       return EB(

           function(err){
               if (err) {
                   if (typeof err ==='object' && err instanceof Error) {
                       throw err;
                   } else {
                       throw new Error(err);
                   }
                   return true;//redundant due to throw, but anyway.
               }
               return false;
           },

           logger===false
              ? self.log //optimization :resolves to noop when logger==false
              : function () {
                   self.info("ignoring returned arguments:",Array.prototype.concat.apply([],arguments));
           },

           function (err) {
               throw typeof err==='string'?new Error(err):err;
           }
       );
   }
}

function getJSON(url,cb){

    var callback=errBack(cb);

    if (typeof url!=='string') {
        return callback.error("getJSON:expecting url as string");
    }

    if (typeof cb!=='function') {
        return callback.error("getJSON:expecting cb as function");
    }

    var redirs = [url],
    fetch = function(u){
        callback.info("hitting:"+u);
        https.get(u, function(res){
            var body = [];
            callback.info({statusCode:res.statusCode});
            if ([301,302].indexOf(res.statusCode)>=0) {
                if (redirs.length>10) {
                    return callback.error("excessive 302 redirects detected");
                } else {
                    if (redirs.indexOf(res.headers.location)<0) {
                        redirs.push(res.headers.location);
                        return fetch(res.headers.location);
                    } else {
                        return callback.error("302 redirect loop detected");
                    }
                }
            } else {
              res.on('data', function(chunk){
                  body.push(chunk);
                  console.info({onData:{chunkSize:chunk.length,chunks:body.length}});
              });
              res.on('end', function(){
                  try {
                      // convert to a single buffer
                      var json = Buffer.concat(body);
                      callback.info({onEnd:{chunks:body.length,bodyLength:body.length}});

                      // parse the buffer as json
                      return callback.result(JSON.parse(json),json);
                  } catch (err) {
                      // read with "bypass refetch" option
                      console.error("exception in getJSON.fetch:",err.message||err);

                      if (json.length>32) {
                        console.error("json==>|"+json.toString('utf-8').substr(0,32)+"|<=== ... (+"+(json.length-32)+" more bytes of json)");
                      } else {
                          console.error("json==>|"+json.toString('utf-8')+"|<=== json");
                      }

                      return callback.error(err,undefined,json);
                  }
              });
            }
        });
    };
    fetch(url);   
}

var TLDs,TLDs_fallback = "com.org.tech.net.biz.info.code.ac.ad.ae.af.ag.ai.al.am.ao.aq.ar.as.at.au.aw.ax.az.ba.bb.bd.be.bf.bg.bh.bi.bj.bm.bn.bo.br.bs.bt.bv.bw.by.bz.ca.cc.cd.cf.cg.ch.ci.ck.cl.cm.cn.co.cr.cu.cv.cw.cx.cy.cz.de.dj.dk.dm.do.dz.ec.ee.eg.er.es.et.eu.fi.fj.fk.fm.fo.fr.ga.gb.gd.ge.gf.gg.gh.gi.gl.gm.gn.gp.gq.gr.gs.gt.gu.gw.gy.hk.hm.hn.hr.ht.hu.id.ie.il.im.in.io.iq.ir.is.it.je.jm.jo.jp.ke.kg.kh.ki.km.kn.kp.kr.kw.ky.kz.la.lb.lc.li.lk.lr.ls.lt.lu.lv.ly.ma.mc.md.me.mg.mh.mk.ml.mm.mn.mo.mp.mq.mr.ms.mt.mu.mv.mw.mx.my.mz.na.nc.ne.nf.ng.ni.nl.no.np.nr.nu.nz.om.pa.pe.pf.pg.ph.pk.pl.pm.pn.pr.ps.pt.pw.py.qa.re.ro.rs.ru.rw.sa.sb.sc.sd.se.sg.sh.si.sj.sk.sl.sm.sn.so.sr.st.su.sv.sx.sy.sz.tc.td.tf.tg.th.tj.tk.tl.tm.tn.to.tr.tt.tv.tw.tz.ua.ug.uk.us.uy.uz.va.vc.ve.vg.vi.vn.vu.wf.ws.ye.yt.za.zm.zw".split(".");
var TLD_url = "https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/umpirsky/tld-list/master/data/en/tld.json";
var TLD_cache = "./tld.json";
var TLD_refresh_msec = 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var TLD_last_msec;
var TLD_default_filter=function(dom){return dom.substr(0,3)!="xn-"};


function getTLDs(cb,filter_func){

    if (typeof cb!=='function') return TLDs;

    var 
    read,fetch,
    CB_WRAP=function(tlds){
        return cb(
            filter_func===false
            ? cb(tlds)
            : tlds.filter(
                typeof filter_func==='function'
                 ? filter_func
                 : TLD_default_filter)
            );
    },
    check_mtime = function(mtime) {
       if (Date.now()-mtime > TLD_refresh_msec) {
           return fetch();
       } 
       if (TLDs) return CB_WRAP (TLDs);
       return read();
    };

    fetch = function(){

        getJSON(TLD_url,function(err,data){
            if (err) {
                console.log("exception in getTLDs.fetch:",err.message||err);
                return read(true);      
            } else {
                TLDs=Object.keys(data);

                fs.writeFile(TLD_cache,JSON.stringify(TLDs),function(err){
                    if (err) {
                        // ignore save error, we have the data
                        CB_WRAP(TLDs);
                    } else {
                        // get mmtime for the file we just made
                        fs.stat(TLD_cache,function(err,stats){
                            if (!err && stats) {
                               TLD_last_msec = stats.mtimeMs; 
                            }
                            CB_WRAP(TLDs);    
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };

    read=function(bypassFetch) {
        fs.readFile(TLD_cache,'utf-8',function(err,json){

            try {
                if (err) {

                    if (bypassFetch) {
                        // after a http errror, we fallback to hardcoded basic list of tlds
                        // if the disk file is not readable
                        console.log("exception in getTLDs.read.bypassFetch:",err.messsage||err);    

                        throw err;
                    }
                    // if the disk read failed, get the data from the CDN server instead
                    return fetch();
                }

                TLDs=JSON.parse(json);
                if (bypassFetch) {
                    // we need to update stats here as fetch called us directly
                    // instead of being called by check_mtime
                    return fs.stat(TLD_cache,function(err,stats){
                        if (err) return fetch();
                        TLD_last_msec =stats.mtimeMs;
                        return CB_WRAP(TLDs);
                    });
                }

            } catch (e){
                // after JSON error, if we aren't in an http fail situation, refetch from cdn server
                if (!bypassFetch) {
                    return fetch();
                }

                // after a http,disk,or json parse error, we fallback to hardcoded basic list of tlds

                console.log("exception in getTLDs.read:",err.messsage||err);    
                TLDs=TLDs_fallback;
            }

            return CB_WRAP(TLDs);
        });
    };

    if (TLD_last_msec) {
        return check_mtime(TLD_last_msec);
    } else {
        fs.stat(TLD_cache,function(err,stats){
            if (err) return fetch();
            TLD_last_msec =stats.mtimeMs;
            return check_mtime(TLD_last_msec);
        });
    }
}

getTLDs(console.log.bind(console));
```