# Node.js Requests returning 301 redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, nginx, http-redirect

I'm brand new to node.js, but I wanted to play around with some basic code and make a few requests. At the moment, I'm playing around with the OCW search (http://www.ocwsearch.com/), and I'm trying to make a few basic requests using their sample search request:

However, no matter what request I try to make (even if I just query google.com), it's returning me

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.7.65</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not too sure what's going on. I've looked up nginx, but most questions asked about it seemed to be asked by people who were setting up their own servers. I've tried using an https request instead, but that returns an error 'ENOTFOUND'.

My code below:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World\n');

    var options = {
      host:'ocwsearch.com',
      path:
      '/api/v1/search.json?q=statistics&contact=http%3a%2f%2fwww.ocwsearch.com%2fabout/',
      method: 'GET'
    }  


    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
      console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
      res.on('data', function(d) {
            process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    });
    req.end();

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    });


}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Sorry if this is a really simple question, and thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Node.JS's HTTP Request module isn't following the redirect you are given.

See this question for more:  [How do you follow an HTTP Redirect in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7323932/362536)

Basically, you can either look through the headers and handle the redirect yourself, or use one of the handful of modules for this.  I've used the "request" library, and have had good luck with it myself.  https://github.com/mikeal/request

Answer (score 18):

For me the website I was trying to GET was redirecting me to the secure protocol. So I changed

```
require('http');
```

to

```
require('https');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var http = require('http');

var find_link = function(link, callback){

  var root =''; 

  var f = function(link){

    http.get(link, function(res) {

      if (res.statusCode == 301) {
        f(res.headers.location);
      } else {
        callback(link);
      } 

    });
 }

  f(link, function(t){i(t,'*')});
}   

find_link('http://somelink.com/mJLsASAK',function(link){
  console.log(link);
});

function i(data){
  console.log( require('util').inspect(data,{depth:null,colors:true}) )
}
```

Comment: so why would `res.statusCode == 301` at this point and where is `i` and what obfuscator did you use to generate this code :P

Comment: oh, `f` is recursive; àla line ~12...LOL

Comment: Added the i function which sure does not make it less confusing .... and as for the obfuscater wow I dont remember writing this I must have been possessed .

Answer (score 4):

This question is old now, but I got the same 301 error and these answers didn't actually help me to solve the problem.

I wrote the same code:

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    }
};

var http = require('http');

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS:',res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ', e.message);
});
console.log(req);

req.end();
```

so after some time I realized that there's a really tiny mistake in this code which is hostname part:

```
 var options = {
     hostname: 'google.com',
     ...
```

you have to add "www." before your URL to get html content, otherwise there would be 301 error.

```
var options = {
     hostname: 'www.google.com',
```

Comment: A 301 response is not an error, it is a permanent redirect and the core basis of this person's question.  The site redirected with an http 301 response and  node.js http doesn't follow redirects, you have to code for that or use one of the many modules which will do it for you.

Comment: thanks you lol, few hours and I didnt notice the www is missing

Comment: For anyone interested in what's going on: adding `www`  "fixes" it because what happens is some servers are setup that if you go to `example.com` it will redirect you to `www.example.com`  and therefore responds with the HTTP status code 301 which means "Moved permanently". Adding `www` solves the issue because it prevents making the server having to redirect you.