# Following redirects in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, proxy, http-headers

I'm working on proxy for downloading files from Google Docs. Since the download urls Google Drive API gives for non-gdrive filetypes (pdf, txt, jpeg) are redirects and having read [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323932/how-do-you-follow-an-http-redirect-in-node-js) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061118/node-js-requests-returning-301-redirects), I decided to use [follow-redirects library](https://github.com/olalonde/follow-redirects). So when you hit `http://localhost:3000/oauth2_download?accessToken=x&url=my_url` where x is my GDrive access_token, url is, say, `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B_31K_MP92hUNjljYjIyMzgtZTBmNS00MGMwLWIxNmQtYjMyNDFiYjY0MTJl&export=download`, the file is supposed to be downloaded. However, the browser sends me to the Google Docs sign-in page which (given that hitting `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B_31K_MP92hUNjljYjIyMzgtZTBmNS00MGMwLWIxNmQtYjMyNDFiYjY0MTJl&export=download` in browser downloads the file if you're logged into Google Docs) means the headers are not being sent correctly. Any idea how should I use 'follow-redirects' library to deal with this issue? Thank you in advance!

```
//var https = require('https');
var https = require('follow-redirects').https;
var app = require('express')();
var urllib = require('url');
// Downloads the file using OAuth2. Tested on Google Drive
app.get('/oauth2_download', function(req, res){
    var url = req.param('url');
    var accessToken = req.param('accessToken');
    var headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken }
    var searchname = urllib.parse(url).search;
    var hostname = urllib.parse(url).hostname;
    var pathname = urllib.parse(url).pathname;
    if (url && accessToken) {
        // downloading file with streaming
        var options = {
            hostname: hostname,
            port: 443,
            path: pathname + searchname,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers
        };
        https.request(options, function(response){
            for (var key in response.headers) {
                res.setHeader(key, response.headers[key]);
            }
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                res.write(chunk);
            });
            response.on('end', function() {
                res.end();
            });
            //console.log("Done downloading using OAuth2");
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }).end();
    } else {
        res.send(404);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but can you try this with mikeal's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module? It follows redirects by default.

Comment: Thanks! I actually started off with that module. The problem was that I couldn't figure out a good way to stream the data in the following fashion: response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                res.write(chunk);
            });