# Why does the "request module" in Node.js accept only the URLs written with protocol?

Tags: node.js, http, get, protocols, node-modules

I want to send a GET request using request module. Here's the code:

```
var requestModule = require('request');
var url = require('url');

var myUrl = 'www.google.com';
var myUrlObj = url.parse(myUrl); 

requestModule(myUrl, myUrlObj , callback);
```

but it doesn't work because myUrlObj has a null value for its "protocol" attribute.

The same code works when:

```
var myUrl = 'http://www.google.com'
```

Why is it so rigid?

Also I tried doing the following to get around this problem:

```
if ( myUrlObj.protocol == null ) {
    myUrl = "http://" + myUrl;
    myUrlObj = url.parse(myUrl);
}
```

But some websites use https, while others use http. So, the above code fails for websites that use https, and the require module throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL comes from user input, default to `http://` and let them enter a protocol for HTTPS. Encourage them to enter a protocol. Most HTTPS websites will redirect you from the HTTP url to the HTTPS URL. You can make the `request` module follow redirects using the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592884/145279).