# GitHub release asset download with node.js

Tags: node.js, github, github-api, nw.js

I want to write an auto downloader in Node.js using the http.get method from a GitHub release using the API and and i receive 302 error. What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) isn't an error:

> The [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) response [status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) 302 Found is a common way of performing [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).

You can handle HTTP 302 Found by retrieving the URL shown in the `Location` response header.

Instead of using `http.get`, you might want to consider using [the `request` library](https://github.com/mikeal/request) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323932/how-do-you-follow-an-http-redirect-in-node-js). `request` should automatically follow the redirect.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and i didn't knew i have to do this.