# Downloading a zip file with Node.js using fs and http module not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im using the following code to download a zip file. If you put the URL into a browser you will see that it starts downloading. But when I use Node to download the zip, the output test.zip file contains this:

```
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://patentscdn.reedtech.com/ipg150804-zip/ipg150804.zip?sv=2014-02-14&amp;sr=b&amp;sig=u1W37AFnH9DAcqc7k4tDABaV14eSlchN8fJJ1%2FOkWEo%3D&amp;st=2015-08-04T04%3A00%3A00Z&amp;se=9999-12-31T05%3A00%3A00Z&amp;sp=r">here</a></body>
```

Heres the Node.js code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = 'http://patents.reedtech.com/downloads/GrantRedBookText/2015/ipg150804.zip';

http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        fs.appendFileSync('test.zip', data);
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log('hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: did the redirect trick work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an HTTP redirect, you can do the following

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
```

this will enable `http` to follow redirects. I suggest you use [request](https://github.com/request/request) library.

Check [How do you follow an HTTP Redirect in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323932/how-do-you-follow-an-http-redirect-in-node-js) for more details

Comment: Thanks this works, only note was that I had to npm install follow-redirects. Also I tried it using request like you suggested and it worked as well. Heres the code `request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip'))`