# Error when accessing (Discord)API with http.get()

Tags: node.js, api, http, get

My problem is I get a 301 error when accessing the Discord API(api/gateway).
In Postman(REST Client), it works fine:

[image]

But if I do it with my code, it always returns a 301 error:

```
function getGateway(){
    http.get({
        host: 'discordapp.com',
        path: '/api/gateway',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': useragent //This is a variable.
        }
    }, function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            var body = [];
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                body = body.join('');
                return body.url;
            });
        } else {
            if (res.statusCode === 429){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    getGateway();
                }, parseInt(JSON.parse(res.headers).Retry-After, 10) * 1000)
            } else {
                console.log('Received non-ok response: ' + res.statusCode);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Output:

```
undefined
Received non-ok response: 301
```

Error code 301 is not even in the API documentation.
Can somebody see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP code 301](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/HTTP_301) means that the URL you are trying to access was moved. One of the reasons may be that it automatically redirects to the HTTPS version of the API.

Unfortunately, it looks like the node `http` module doesn't handle following redirects. I would suggest one of these options:

- use the awesome [request](https://github.com/request/request) module
- find where the URL you are calling is trying to redirect you: the body of the response should contain information about this
- use the [follow-redirects](https://github.com/olalonde/follow-redirects) module as a drop-in replacement for the `http` one, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390241/2215166)