# How to redirect to target url using node 'http'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I am executing below code snippet but it is not redirecting to actual page.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/search?q=hello+world'
};

http.get(options, function(resp){
resp.setEncoding('utf8');
  resp.on('data', function(chunk){
    //do something with chunk
console.log('================\n\n', chunk);
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Command fire :

```
node sample.js
```

Output :

```
================

 <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world&amp;gws_rd=cr&amp;dcr=0&amp;ei=Wd3xWd_nBITovgSl9bXwCA">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I want to get entire page html but not this instead of I want results for hello world.

Comment: google.com is a relative address. you need to change this to Http://google.com

Comment: Then I get this Got error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://www.google.com http://www.google.com:80

Comment: Did you test it without port number?

Comment: Yes I did that too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you follow an HTTP Redirect in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323932/how-do-you-follow-an-http-redirect-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

use `resp.redirect('url');` for redirect to the required page.

Basically `node js` is developed for `create server`.But incidently it has come to `server side`..so its soo diffcult to make application in `core node js`..you can try atleast any `frameworks` such as `express js`..https://expressjs.com/ just go through this `strong & easy & famous` framework..if you dont like it then go to another

Comment: Getting this TypeError: resp.redirect is not a function

Comment: The thing is I don't want to open this in browser by createServer() method and want to access the data by console itself

Comment: in console `html` won't work..it shows full code always

Comment: Yes agreed. I just need to see entire code not just html

Comment: i think google doesn't allow to get data like `google doesn't show in iframe`

Comment: But any other url is giving the same kind of redirection error page

Comment: that website should have `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` access

Answer (score 0):

Try putting instead of utf8 - “utf-8” ; with the dash sign

Comment: Still same results

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is to follow the redirect. See this other  question for possible answers: [How do you follow an HTTP Redirect in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323932/how-do-you-follow-an-http-redirect-in-node-js)