# How to download mp3 file from a url that redirects? (In Node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, node-modules

I retrieve this URL from using some previous logic - https://bots.rocket.chat/file-upload/ZSzGtWdXyP8DZwrQ9/Audio%20record.mp3

Now I need to download it for further processing, but I tried using the download, axios.request, and other packages available. My best guess for them failing is that the actual URL of the audio is different then what I retrieved.

Something like (It changes after a while) -https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.use1.cloud.rocket.chat/KqCQiHfeFaKdSEGvy/uploads/GENERAL/XmYemgXfudSzBQstR/ZSzGtWdXyP8DZwrQ9?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAILPK6SHTK5RJZLHQ%2F20190518%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190518T115900Z&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=8d793d14fbb33d78b084a5ed153106ba19440feb7bf05525aeed530b5a0907f9&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

Also, I'm able to download the file using the same code when I provide it with the end URL (the longer one).
So need to figure out how to reach that URL in node.

Also to access the first URL you need to make an account on https://bots.rocket.chat

This is the code I have currently. The url passed to getFile function is the is a relative path which I append to the prefix url to form the above mentioned shorter URL, and call axios and this doesn't work.

But when I replace the url with a long url which is similar to the longer one posted above the code works just fine.

```
async function getFile(url) {
  var fs = require('fs');
  return await axios.request({
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    followAllRedirects: true,
    url: `https://bots.rocket.chat${url}`,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    },
  }).then((result) => {
    const outputFilename = 'file2.mp3';
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFilename, result.data);
    return outputFilename;
  })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  ;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you follow an HTTP Redirect in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323932/how-do-you-follow-an-http-redirect-in-node-js)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried all the methods mentioned there but to no avail.
Also, I have to download the mp3 file after following the link.

Comment: do you have some current code that you can share?

Comment: Added my current code.